# callig str when using functions

Tags: python, function

im writing some code to print a triangle with so many rows but when i try it it says,

```
how many rows in the triangle 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "U:\School\Homework\year 8\module 3\IT\python\lesson 10\extention          task set by Mr Huckitns.py", line 6, in <module>
    triangle(5)
  File "U:\School\Homework\year 8\module 3\IT\python\lesson 10\extention     task set by Mr Huckitns.py", line 5, in triangle
    print((x*(str(" ")))(int(i)*(str("*")))((int(row)-int(i))*(str(" "))))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

anybodyknow whats going on here

```
the code i am using is
inttrow=int(input("how many rows in the triangle "))
def triangle(row):
for i in range(1,row):
    x=int(inttrow)-int(i)
    print((x*(str(" ")))(int(i)*(str("*")))((int(row)-int(i))*(str(" "))))
triangle(5)
```

Comment: Please include the code in your post, not as a comment. And use the built-in code formatting (backticks or indent) to make it easier to read.

Comment: I have no idea what that `print` line is supposed to do. It looks like you're missing a bunch of operators.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the punctuation in your print statement.  You're printing three strings in succession, but you forgot to put any concatenation operation between them.  Try this:

```
print ((x*(str(" "))) + (int(i)*(str("*"))) + ((int(row)-int(i))*(str(" "))))
```

Further, why are you doing all these type coercions -- all of those variables already have the proper types.  Cut it down to this:

```
print (x*" " + i*"*" + (row-i)*" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to contatenate strings by placing them near each other in the code like this:

```
("hello")(" ")("world")
```

Try that on the command line and see what happens. It is not the syntax of the language you are using. Then try using the plus sign.

```
"hello" + " " + "world"
```